# Name for new socket

Tags: c++, sockets, server, winsock

I am learning socket programming, i had a problem. I want when people connecting to my server, i see his name(For example "on server connected Richard" ). How assign name to socket. P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. I mean that you don't "assign a name to a socket". Instead you should keep a structure of some kind containing the socket, and all associated data that's needed for that connection, like the connected users name.

For example something similar to

```
struct user
{
    SOCKET      socket;  // The users connected socket
    std::string name;    // The name of the connected user
    // TODO: Other attributes needed for the user or the users connection
};
```

Exactly how to get the user-name is another matter for another question (though I could give you a hint: States).

Comment: I understand the client needs to pass his name to the represented structure, how do this?